# Bound of prime given Primorial

Tags: number-theory

Let $D$ be the primorial of the first $k$ primes. I want to approximate $p_k$. Is the following right?

Since $D = e^{(1+o(1))k\log k}$ and $\quad k \sim p_k / \log p_k $
we have

$$D \sim e^{(1+o(1))(p_k/\log p_k) (\log (p_k)-\log\log p_k))}\ll e^{(1+o(1))p_k}$$

so
$$p_k \gg \log D.$$

Comment: This is valid, and even the stronger statement $p_k \sim \log D$ is valid—this is one equivalent formulation of the prime number theorem.

Comment: @GregMartin Right, because the $\ll$ on the first equation can also be a $\sim$?

Comment: Well, technically no because $\sim$ in the exponents doesn't imply $\sim$ for the exponential expressions themselves—but morally yes because we take logarithms before asserting $\sim$.